# How to SUM Total in Ajax n Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I'm Beginner at Ajax or JS
I want to display the results of the sum from the database
using ajax by user "A" and by date

But only show COUNT result (ex: 4) not (ex: $ 120.00)

```
 public function ajax_dashboard()
{
    date_default_timezone_set($this->setting->timezone);
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $year = date("Y"); 
    $queue = Sale::find('all', array('conditions' => array('status = ?', '0')));;
    $onproccess = Sale::find('all', array('conditions' => array('status = ?', '1')));;
    $finish = Sale::find('all', array('conditions' => array('status = ?', '2')));;
    $unpaid = Sale::find('all', array('conditions' => array('status = ?', '1')));;
    $todaysales = Sale::find('all', array('conditions' => array('created_by = ?', 'cashier')=> array('created_at = ?', '$date')));;

    $data = array(
        "queue" => $queue,
        "onproccess" => $onprocess,
        "finish" => $finish,
        "unpaid" => $unpaid,
        "todaysales" => $todaysales
    );
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

How to SUM Total Price / todaysales by Specific User (cashier)?

Thanks Before :)

Comment: Where is your ajax part of code?

Comment: the code attached is completely unrelated to your question